# Hazelcast: How to guarantee an EventListener never misses any events?

Tags: java, hazelcast

Through Hazelcast's Java client I am able to successfully add an `EntryListener` and the listener is called as expected when entries are added or updated. So far so good.

But sometimes the client application becomes disconnected from the cluster. When this happens the client often reconnects automatically and the client has to once again add the listener. But during this brief period (between disconnection and adding the listener again), there is a chance that events are missed.

Another time that events maybe missed is if the client needs to be restart.

Is there a way to guarantee that an `EntryListener` receives **all** events?

Answer (score 1):

Event listeners work in a fire&forget manner, so there is no way to receive past events.

However; there's **ReliableTopic**, which stores the last N events in a ringbuffer. And if you listen it with a **ReliableMessageListener**, it can store the event id's locally and resume from the last received event in case of a disconnection etc. Please check out the interfaces of those two.